# Magento and Openerp Integration by using Magento Integration [OpenERP module]

Tags: magento, odoo

Magento is successfully installed in WAMP Server . Also  magento connecter has been added.

Later downloaded the module 'magento_integration__develop' module and placed  inside  addons directory. Clicking upon update module of the openerp pops up following error .

```
OpenERP Server Error
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-   231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1132, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 42, in proxy
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 103, in send


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 197, in execute
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\module\wizard\base_module_update.py", line 42, in update_module
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231 029\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 617, in update_list
 File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 580, in load_addons
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 133, in load_module
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\magento_integration-develop\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006- 231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\magento_integration-develop\magento_.py", line 17, in    <module>
  ImportError: No module named magento
```

Answer (score 0):

hte problem seems it cant find magento module

https://openerp-magento-connector.readthedocs.org/en/develop/introduction.html

you need to run python setup.py install